# How to access fields of ASPNetUsers table created by default with project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I asked a very similar question yesterday, but didn't do a good job of framing it clearly (hence no answers :)). So, I'm going to take one more shot.

I'm working with C# .NET web forms (starting out). When I make a new project, it by default has the functionality for register and login and the data is also stored in the default DB in a table called AspNetUsers. This table has some standard fields like user id, username, etc. It does not have first and last names. Fist, how do I go about adding fields to this table and making them accessible?

Next, I want to integrate this data with other tables I am creating. For example, I have a table (lets call it the "actions" table) that records an entry when ever a user will take an action. I have figured out how to access the user name each time the user takes this action. But now, I want to be able to display this action later to another set of users along with the user name, email, phone number and other details of the user that took the action. I can store the user name each time the user takes the action in the "actions" table. But now I need to join with the ASPNetUsers table and obtain the other details of that user. How do I do this?

If I wanted to do this for another data type that I created in the Models folder, I could access the fields in an object oriented way. But the ASPNetUsers table doesn't seem to have a class associated with it.

Edit:
I don't have code that attempts what I am asking above because I have no idea where to start. However, I did attempt to solve the problem an alternate way. I reckoned that I would create my own user class and just populate that every time some one registers. So, I created the class like so -

```
public class User
 {
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

Then I went to the Register.aspx.cs class and added the following code to the CreateUser_Click method, hoping that a new user would be added to this new table I created.-

```
 User SuccessfullyRegisteredUser = new User
            {
                UserID = 10,
                Id = "asd-3021-104",
                Name = "new user",
                Email = Email.Text
            };
            DataContext context = new DataContext();
            context.Users.Add(SuccessfullyRegisteredUser);
```

However, when I register as a dummy user and try to look at the Users table, this record I created is not there.

Comment: You should have edited the other question. But even then... you ask several questions in one post. That doesn't work well at Stack Overflow. And the wording is very very vague. You better show code in which you try to achieve what you want, even if it doesn't succeed.

Comment: @Gret - I will delete the old question. I have added my attempt at a solution through an alternate (but less desirable) approach here.